# Invalid selector exception using XPath expression (Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am using the Xpathchecker Firefox plugin to get the XPath expression, but when I run this code:

```java
private void srch() throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
  driver.get(TestURL);

  WebElement input1 = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_user_input"));
  input1.sendKeys("guest");

  WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_password_input"));
  input2.sendKeys("guest");

  WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_signin_button"));
  btn.click();

  WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.id("header_search_text_field"));
  w1.sendKeys("tsk");

  //WebElement resulttable = driver.findElement(By.id("search_results_table"));
  //System.out.println(resulttable.getSize());
  List <WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("id('search_results_table')/x:tbody/x:tr"));
  System.out.println(rows.size());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
The given selector id('search_results_table')/x:tbody/x:tr is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression id('search_results_table')/x:tbody/x:tr because of the following error:
[Exception... "An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces"  code: "14" nsresult: "0x8053000e (NamespaceError)"  location: "file:///C:/Users/orsyp/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8101865731711582627webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 5916"]
Command duration or timeout: 109 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: 9cbc470a-c211-46ce-8bb1-ccdb9c66ff1e
```

And here is my HTML code. As you can see, this is a dynamic table:

```html
<table id="search_results_table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed  table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
            <td>
               <a href="#/en/object?company=WAR001&area=X&mu=BIST_CE691&name=TSK(BEN701JU50)(000)">
              <p style="font-size:11px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide html code, so I'll be able to help you with xpath. Your xpath is not valid.

Comment: Thanks, HTML code added

Comment: Why have you made several questions about this? It was explained to you before, that isn't a valid XPath in any sense. You are also providing old log files to us: `'2013-08-12 15:42:01`

Comment: Sorry I got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want all rows in the *tbody*, the XPath expression should be:

```
//table[@id='search_results_table']/tbody/tr
```